# php - how execute a sqlsrv stored procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I have a successful connection to SQL Server using SQLSRV in my PHP script:

```
$name = 'SERVERNAME';
$db  = 'DBNAME';
$par = array("Database"=>$db);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($name, $par);
```

Also I have the following T-SQL script:

```
Declare @dt datetime;
SET @dt = GETDATE();
EXEC oik..SrezLTGES @Cat = 'Ë', @Ids = '140539,140540,140589,150395,180395,180396,180445',@Time = @dt
```

The procedure parameters are:

[image]

I don't know how to execute this query in PHP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach here is to parameterize the statement and use `sqlsrv_query()`. As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15), the *sqlsrv_query function is well-suited for one-time queries and should be the default choice to execute queries unless special circumstances apply* and *sqlsrv_query function does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries*.

The stored procedure has `varchar` parameters (and I'm almost sure, that you are using a cyrillic collation), so you may need to use the appropriate encoding (`"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"` or `"CharacterSet" => SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR` in the connection options) and/or character set conversion on the parameters values (with `iconv()` for example). Reading [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) is a good starting point.

If the stored procedure returns data, you may try to use `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` to retrieve the returned data. You may also use `SET NOCOUNT ON` to prevent SQL Server from passing the count of the affected rows as part of the result set.

The following example, based on your code, is a possible solution to your problem:

```
<?php
// Connection
$server   = "SERVERNAME";
$database = "DBNAME";
$cinfo = array(
    "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8",
    "Database" => $database
);
$con = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if ($con === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

// Statement
$sql = "
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @dt datetime;
    SET @dt = GETDATE();
    EXEC oik..SrezLTGES 
        @Cat = ?, 
        @Ids = ?, 
        @Time = @dt,
        @TimeIsSummer = 1,
        @ShowSystemTime = 1
";      
$params = array("Ë", "140539,140540,140589,150395,180395,180396,180445");
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql, $params);
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

// Data
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo print_r($row, true);
}

// End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. But how i can get result data from $stmt???